# Python 2.7: Using reduce to verify that elements are in a list

Tags: python, reduce

While experimenting with the reduce function, I've observed behavior that I can't explain to myself. 
Say, there are 2 lists:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "z"]
b = ["b", "z", "a"]
```

I woud like to verify whether all elements of the list ***b*** are in the list ***a*** using ***reduce***. So, I try:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: (x in a) and (y in a), b)
```

and get **False** instead of expected **True**.

So, why do I get **False**?

P.S.: I know that there are other ways to verify if all list's elements are in another list, f.i. using sets and *issuperset*. I just wonder why the reduce function works this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
b = ["b", "z", "a"]
reduce(lambda x,y: (x in a) and (y in a), b)
```

is equivalent to:

```
(("b" in a) and ("z" in a)) in a and ("a" in a)
```

which calculates to:

```
(True in a) and ("a" in a)
```